# How functions are behaving unusual?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<body onload="myFunction()"><form name="dob">
<input type="number" name="dobd">
</form>
<p id="dd"></p>
<p id="mm"></p>
<p id="yy"></p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = new Date().getDate();
document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML = new Date().getMonth();
document.getElementById('yy').innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
}
function myFunction2(){
}
</script>
```

Please see the code, when I am writing like this, everything is performing good but when I am adding some variable or anything else on the 2nd function, every data from the 1st is turning to blank. like this.

```
<body onload="myFunction()"><form name="dob">
<input type="number" name="dobd">
</form>
<p id="dd"></p>
<p id="mm"></p>
<p id="yy"></p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = new Date().getDate();
document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML = new Date().getMonth();
document.getElementById('yy').innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
}
function myFunction2(){
var = a;
}
</script>
```

Then what is the problem? How can it be possible?

Comment: Because your variable declaration is wrong

Comment: When you add bad javascript, like your invalid var declaration, it will stop parsing as soon as it reads it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the name of the variable in the variable declaration `var = a`.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = new Date().getDate();
document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML = new Date().getMonth();
document.getElementById('yy').innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
}
function myFunction2(){
var x= a;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()"><form name="dob">
<input type="number" name="dobd">
</form>
<p id="dd"></p>
<p id="mm"></p>
<p id="yy"></p>
</body>
</html>
```